# Django-polymorphic and abstract parent class?

Tags: django

I have never used django-polymorphic lib in my projects, so I have some important questions about your experience.

1) Is it possible to set up the parent class abstract? 
In my project I need some easy access to children objects, something like this:

```
>>> Project.objects.all()
>>> [ <XxxProject:    id 1, topic "Department Party">,
 <ArtProject:      id 2, topic "Painting with Tim", artist "T. Turner">,
 <ResearchProject: id 3, topic "Swallow Aerodynamics", supervisor "Dr. Winter">]
```

and also is important to me to avoid INNER JOIN, so I was thinking to write one big model with all possible attributes, and next design some proxy models. 
Other solution is this polymorphic lib, but perfect if I could make parent class abstract.
Which solutions is better and why in your opinion?

2) How expensive is to use polymorphic lib in practice? How you perceive this lib on your production projects? Is this a potential bottleneck of performance?

Comment: No you can't make a base model abstract. I'm using it in staging, albeit not production, and I'm not experiencing a performance hit yet.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I decided to use polymorphic, looks really nice.